# SQL - How to get rows within a date period that are within another date period?

Tags: sql, django, filter, logic

I have the following table in the DDBB:

[image]

On the other side, i have an interface with an start and end filter parameters.

So i want to understand how to query the table to only get the data from the table which period are within the values introduces by the user.

Next I present the 3 scenarios possible. If i need to create one query per each scenario is ok:

- Scenario 1:If the users only defines start = 03/01/2021, then the expected output should be rows with id 3,5 and 6.
- Scenario 2:if the users only defines end = 03/01/2021, then the expected output shoud be rows with id 1 and 2.
- Scenario 3:if the users defines start =03/01/2021 and end=05/01/2021 then the expected output should be rows with id 3 and 5.

Hope that makes sense.

Thanks

Comment: You need to use `start>=` for 1, `end<=` for 2 and `start>= amd end<=` for 3

Comment: You need use .filter(**Kwargs) https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/

Comment: Hi, I do not think is that easy. Against what filter parameter i should do this?

Comment: Yes, i know how to make a query, what i am looking for is to understand the logic.

Comment: .filter(start_date__gt = yourDatetime,end_date__lt = yourEndDatetime,pk='1,2')

Comment: Hi @Nathan_Sav, i do not think your logic cover all scenarios. Also, agains what filter parameters should I apply the queries? Agains the filter_start or filter_end or both

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that `start_date` and `end_date` here are [**`DateField`s** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#datefield), and that you have a dictionary with a `'start'` and `'end'` as (optional) key, and these map to `date` object, so a possible dictionary could be:

```
# scenario 3
from datetime import date

data = {
    'start': date(2021, 1, 3),
    'end': date(2021, 1, 5)
}
```

If you do not want to filter on `start` and/or `end`, then either the key is *not* in the dictionary `data`, or it maps to `None`.

You can make a filter with:

```
filtr = {
    lu: data[ky]
    ky, lu in (('start', 'start_date__gte'), ('end', 'end_date__lte'))
    if data.get(ky)
}
result = MyModel.objects.filter(**filtr)
```

This will then filter the `MyModel` objects to only retrieve `MyModel`s where the `start_date` and `end_date` are within bounds.